# Question on step of existing proof regarding area of disk

Tags: calculus, integration

The following proof is from Apostol Calculus V1 Page 91.  I'm unsure how near the end of the proof:

$2r \int^1_{-1} \sqrt{r^2 - (rx)^2} dx = 2r^2 \int^1_{-1} \sqrt{1 - x^2} dx$.

How is $r * r$ on the LHS?

I'm using an image because I'm concerned the OCR may have caused on error.

[image]

Comment: Please note it is $g(rx)$ and $d(rx) = rdx$

Answer (score 1):

They factored the $r$ out of the square root, and then out of the integral because it is constant with respect to $x$:
\begin{align*}
2r \int^1_{-1} \sqrt{r^2 - (rx)^2} dx &= 2r\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{r^{2}(1 - x^2})\,dx\\
&=2r\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{r^2}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx\\
&=2r\int_{-1}^{1}r\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx\\
&=2r^2\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

An $r$ has been factored out of  the integrand.  That is, $\sqrt{r^2-(rx)^2}=\sqrt{r^2(1-x^2)}=r\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

you have:
$$2r\sqrt{r^2-(rx)^2}=2r\sqrt{r^2(1-x^2)}=2r|r|\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
and if $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$ this simplifies to:
$$2r^2\sqrt{1-x^2}$$